# Where is Dreadjudge's Illusion 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was doing a Nephalem Rift, and I got thrown into this map.
However, the map was labelled as Dreadjudge's Illusion 3.

The reason why I'm asking this is because the map has A LOT of chests and I want to go back there. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rifts are mostly randomized. The names, especially, bear absolutely no meaning on the content.

Some rifts have cows, some have ponies, and some are full of goblins. You got lucky to get one that happened to be full of chests. But there is *nothing* you can do to influence which rift you get.

Just keep doing rifts, and eventually you might get lucky again.

Comment: *[off-topic derail on what it means to randomize a level "completely" pruned]*